# Javascript equivalent of Java's matcher.matches

Tags: javascript

Is there any function in `Javascript` that replicates Java's `matcher.matches()`?

Ok, let me narrow it down.

JAVA: The matches function in java tries to match the input regex against an entire string, say the regex is "^http" and the string is "http://www.xxx.zzz", the output is false where as ^http.* returns true.

JAVASCRIPT: In js, the function i tried was ".test()" which returned true even when the regex is "^http" for the same input string.

I use java in server side and js in client side, and I want to express the same behaviour on both. Is there any other method in js that replicates the matches function in java

Comment: Javascript has match https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match Can you specify exactly what are you looking to match? Asserting whether java and javascript match are same is a very broad question. You need to narrow it down

Comment: @gurvinder372 I have edited my question.Please do let me know if its still unclear!!

Comment: So, you want to return true if it match the entire string or else false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The matches function in java tries to match the input regex against an entire string

There is no such function in JavaScript. You'll need to manually [anchor your regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to the begin and end of the string.

```
/^http$/.test("http://www.xxx.zzz") // false
```